# Not null column to shift left in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I am working on MySQL database.
I have a table `empreporting`, this table contains
`employeeid` and `reportingemployeeid` columns

```
SELECT e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` AS Level0,e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` AS Level1,e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` AS Level2,e1.`EmployeeId` AS Level3
FROM empreporting e1
LEFT JOIN empreporting e2 ON e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e2.`EmployeeId`
LEFT JOIN empreporting e3 ON e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e3.`EmployeeId`
```

the above query giving below result:

```
Level0  Level1  Level2  Level3

\N      \N      379      369

\N      379     484      372

\N      \N      \N       379
```

Required result format is :

```
Level0  Level1  Level2  Level3

379      369     \N      \N

379      484     372     \N

379      \N      \N      \N
```

Pls any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Prakash

Answer (score 2):

Finally Written Query

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId`+1000000 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e2.`ReportingEmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`ReportingEmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`EmployeeId`  IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`EmployeeId` 
END AS Level0,
CASE 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e2.`ReportingEmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`ReportingEmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`EmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`EmployeeId`  IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
END AS Level1,
CASE 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`ReportingEmployeeId`
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`EmployeeId` 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`EmployeeId`  IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
END AS Level2,
CASE
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN e1.`EmployeeId` 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN NULL 
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` IS NULL AND e1.`EmployeeId`  IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
END AS  Level3
FROM empreporting e1
LEFT JOIN empreporting e2 ON e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e2.`EmployeeId` 
LEFT JOIN empreporting e3 ON e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e3.`EmployeeId`
```

Comment: ...THEN e3.`ReportingEmployeeId`+1000000?  Where did that come from? Also upvote, if for no other reason than the fact that you wrote it all out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT e1.EmployeeId AS Level0,e2.`EmployeeId` AS Level1,e3.`EmployeeId` AS Level2,e3.`ReportingEmployeeId` AS Level3
FROM empreporting e1
LEFT JOIN empreporting e2 ON e1.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e2.`EmployeeId`
LEFT JOIN empreporting e3 ON e2.`ReportingEmployeeId` = e3.`EmployeeId`
```